# How can I get rid of the annoying language indicator in Windows 8+

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, language, chinese, ime

If you are using an IME to type in Windows 8+, you might have seen this:

[image]

Before Windows 8, Windows won't show this 英/中 box to indicate which language you are typing in. Instead, old Windows would only show this in the taskbar. However for some reason, some of the designers in Microsoft decided that it would be a great idea to move it right beneath the place where you are typing at.

The box is quite annoying, and it is not even transparent, which often blocks the text behind it. To make it worse, you can click on it and doesn't let click events pass through it. There's no way of quickly make it disappears without waiting for seconds.

Windows 10 has the exact same issue. Apparently they don't pay much attention to IME users, or they just not care.

The question is, how do I get rid of this goshdarn box?

Answer (score 0):

See below if you can read Chinese.
http://answers.microsoft.com/zh-hant/windows/forum/windows_10-ime/%E5%A6%82%E4%BD%95%E9%9A%B1%E8%97%8F%E4%B8%AD/9312e210-1067-4464-b46c-a835d8facef1

Comment: Thanks for showing me that link, however on that page it seems that nobody has actually solved this problem.

Comment: At my end, the problem has been solved because the box does not appear again.